# Codeblocks compiler not displaying output

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am trying to solve this problem below. As far as I know, everything is correct logically and syntax wise. However, when I click run, the black cmd window pops up, it displays the answers to problems 1-4 (those have been omitted because they are irrelevant, and problem 5 has been cropped out), but nothing happens at the problem 6 function, and I never get the "process returned 0 (0x0) execution time: xxxx s". Is there something I am doing wrong, or is it the compiler?
Note: I'm not asking for the answer. I just want to know why it isn't displaying.

```
        /* problem 6   Find the difference between the sum of the squares of the first 100 numbers and the square of the sum*/
        void problem6()
        {
            int sum_of_squares;
            int square_of_sums;
            int counter;
            int answer;
            int x;

            for(x=1; x=100; x++)
            {
                sum_of_squares += (x*x);
                counter += x;
            }
            square_of_sums = (counter*counter);
            answer = square_of_sums - sum_of_squares;
            printf("Problem 6 answer: %d", answer);
        }

       /* problem5(); */
        problem6();
```

Comment: `for(x=1; x=100; x++)` is it a typo? `x<=100`?

Comment: also, assign `int sum_of_squares=0;` as you are using `sum_of_squares += (x*x);` in for loop. `int counter=0;`  its in forloop `counter += x;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(=) is an assignment operator. Your condition should be (x<=100) or (x!=101). And you have not initialized sum_of_squares,square_of_sums and counter with any value so they contain garbage values.

```
void problem6()
        {
            int sum_of_squares=0;
            int square_of_sums=0;
            int counter=0;
            int answer;
            int x;

            for(x=1; x<=100; x++)
            {
                sum_of_squares += (x*x);
                counter += x;
            }
            square_of_sums = (counter*counter);
            answer = square_of_sums - sum_of_squares;
            printf("Problem 6 answer: %d", answer);
        }
```